# DataOutputStream.writeBytes adds zero-bytes

Tags: java, tcp

I have a small TCP server program and a corresponding client, and they communicate via ServerSocket and Socket classes and DataInputStream/DataOutputStream. And I have a problem with sending Strings to the server.

```
connection = new Socket("localhost", 2233);

outStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());

outStream.writeBytes(fileName);
```

fileName is, at this point in time, a hard-coded String with the value "listener.jardesc". The server reads the string with the following code:

```
inStream = new DataInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

String fileName = inStream.readLine();
```

The string is received properly, but three zero-value bytes have been added to the end. Why is that and how can I stop it from happening? (I could, of course, trim the received string or somehow else stop this problem from mattering, but I'd rather prevent the problem completely)

Comment: What version of Java?  That readLine() method is deprecated in Java 5, 6 & 7.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29

Comment: Why do you think you can use `readLine` after using `writeBytes`? Did you write `"listener.jardesc\n"`? And how do you conclude that there are three zero-bytes at the end, how do you inspect your value?

Comment: Java 7.
No, just "listener.jardesc". I inspect it by turning it into char[] and printing the corresponding number values to the console.

Comment: It *should* not give you these zero-bytes, and I'm inclined to think that there is some code that you haven't posted that somehow causes the problem. But I have a suggestion to try: instead of `writeBytes` and `readLine`, use `writeUTF` and `readUTF`. These methods properly take care of character encoding, but more importantly, they prefix the string with the number of bytes needed to write the string, and the reader uses that to only read as many bytes as written.

Comment: Converting what to chars? A String already is chars. Where did you get the bytes from for this conversion?

Comment: char[] chars = fileName.toCharArray();
   for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) System.out.print((int) chars[i] + " ");

Erwin, thanks for the writeUTF/readUTF suggestion, everything seems to be working now!

Answer (score 0):

I'm just going to throw this out there.  You're using the readLine() method which has been deprecated in Java 5, 6 & 7.  The API docs state quite clearly that this method "does not properly convert bytes to characters".  I would read it as bytes or use a Buffered Reader.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readLine%28%29

Answer (score 0):

writeBytes() does not add extra bytes.

The code  you've written is invalid, as you aren't writing a newline. Therefore it doesn't work, and blocks forever in readLine().

In trying to debug this you appear to have read the bytes some other way, probably with read(); and to have ignored the return value returned by read, and to have concluded that read() filled the buffer you provided, when it didn't, leaving three bytes in their initial state, which is zero.